# sveltekit-i18n not loading translations

Tags: localization, sveltekit

I have a project that I am trying to use loaders from `sveltekit-i18n` like shown [here](https://github.com/sveltekit-i18n/lib/tree/master/examples/loaders/src). I have setup my translations in `$lib/translations` folder and I have defined the loaders. My config file in `$lib/tranlations/index.js` look like this:

```js
import i18n from 'sveltekit-i18n';
import lang from './lang.json';

/** @type {import('sveltekit-i18n').Config} */
export const config = {
  translations: {
    en: { lang },
    es: { lang },
  },
  loaders: [
    {
      locale: 'en',
      key: 'home',
      routes: ['/'],
      loader: async () => (await import('./en/home.json')).default
    },
    {
      locale: 'es',
      key: 'home',
      routes: ['/'],
      loader: async () => (await import('./es/home.json')).default
    },
    {
      locale: 'en',
      key: 'login',
      routes: ['/login'],
      loader: async () => (await import('./en/login.json')).default
    },
    {
      locale: 'es',
      key: 'login',
      routes: ['/login'],
      loader: async () => (await import('./es/login.json')).default
    }
  ],
};

export const { t, locale, locales, loading, loadTranslations } = new i18n(config);
```

my lang.json file looks like this:

```json
{
  "en": "English (UK)",
  "es": "Español"
}
```

and my root layout.js looks like this:

```js
import {browser} from '$app/environment';
import {currentLocale} from "$stores/locale";
import { loadTranslations } from '$lib/translations';

const getCurrentLocale = () => {
    const userLocale =
        window.navigator.languages && window.navigator.languages.length
            ? window.navigator.languages[0]
            : window.navigator.language;
    return {
        userLocale
    }
}
/** @type {import('LayoutLoad')} */
export const load = async ({url}) => {
    const {pathName} = url;

    if (browser) {
        console.log('Browser')
        const {userLocale} = getCurrentLocale();
        currentLocale.set(userLocale);
        await loadTranslations('en', pathName);
        console.log(userLocale)
    } else {
        console.log('Server')
        currentLocale.set('en')
        await loadTranslations('en', pathName);
    }

    console.log(browser)
    return {}
}
```

Does someone see something I am missing?

when I do something like:

```
<p>{$t('key.translation')}</p>
```

It just renders `<p> key.translation </p>`

Any ideas?

Thanks